# "... a molecule derived from ATP "

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am not sure I understood the following passage correctly .

> In the first step of glycolysis, the glucose ring is phosphorylated. **Phosphorylation is the process of adding a phosphate group to a molecule derived from ATP.** As a result, at this point in glycolysis, 1 molecule of ATP has been consumed.

[Source]
http://www.sparknotes.com/biology/cellrespiration/glycolysis/section1.rhtml

Is it the phosphate group, or the molecule, that is **derived from ATP** ?

And can we say "coming from" instead of "derived" here?

Comment: All you need is "a molecule derived from ATP". It means just that. The rest are modifying phrases. Your thinking on the options would be useful.

Comment: **Derived** is the preferred verb in this context, but sometimes you might see or hear *based on* or *built from* or a number of other such phrases.  *Coming from* is not idiomatic in this setting.

Comment: Is the text written by a native speaker? Linguistically the comments and the answer are correct, **but the phosphate group actually does come from ATP in this process** - look for an alternative information source (the one with formulae, that's simpler than text in these cases), and/or ask about the origin of the Pi group in glycolysis on biology SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building up in pieces:

> Phosphorylation is a process.
>
> Phosphorylation  is the process of doing something to something else.
>
> Phosphorylation the process of adding a phosphate group to (something.)
>
> Phosphorylation is a process of adding a phosphate group to (a molecule derived from ATP.)

---

If the phosphate group were derived from XYZ, the sentence could be rephrased:

> Phosphorylation is a process of adding an XYZ-derived phosphate group to a molecule.

NOTE LUCKY"S COMMENT ABOVE:  This answer addresses understanding the sentence as written.  It may not be written correctly.  *"Linguistically the comments and the answer are correct, but the phosphate group actually does come from ATP in this process - look for an alternative information source (the one with formulae, that's simpler than text in these cases), and/or ask about the origin of the Pi group in glycolysis on biology SE" - Lucky*